# Trying to select records from mysql using php, the results are in json without the identifiers

Tags: php, mysql, json

As mentioned, I am getting a JSON string with out the identifiers. The code I am using is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/content/scripts/jquery/v2.1.3/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2> Client example </h2>
        <h3>Output: </h3>
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "{username}";
    $pass = "{password}";
    $databaseName = "{database}";
    $tableName = "{table}";

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
    $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    echo json_encode($array);
?>
</body>
```

My results are:

> ["2d791c8b-d8cf-11e4-a712-002590f3d888","********","********"]

I am extremely new to PHP and MySQL, so be gentle.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: sorry... 1. Why are there no identifiers to the JSON string should be like ID, UserName and Password? 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead. Note that `mysql_*()` is deprecated, so you shouldn't use it for new code. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Using the wrong function. mysql_fetch_row will give you an indexed result. You are looking for something like mysql_fetch_assoc. But keep in mind, that all these mysql_* function are deprecated/unsecure and you are highly encouraged to use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: @JohnSchultz Please add the question in question body instead of comments , so most of people can see it and work on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_row` returns an enumerated array

```
[0] => "2d791c8b-d8cf-11e4-a712-002590f3d888"
```

`mysql_fetch_array` returns an associative array

```
["key"] => "2d791c8b-d8cf-11e4-a712-002590f3d888"
```

mysql_* functions are now defunct, preceded with MySQLi/PDO.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically, try using this:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "{username}";
$pass = "{password}";
$databaseName = "{database}";
$tableName = "{table}";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

But rockerBOO is right, look at at least mysqli